# ie7 input type=file can enter text input

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7

I have weird issue,in ie7 the input type=file, the textbox can accept text entry unlike firefox, it automaticaly launch the file browser and in chrome you really have to click the Browse button to browse for a file to upload.

thanks.

Comment: Different browsers treat certain elements differently. For example Chrome allows textarea to be resized by default. Why do you need to allow text to be entered? And if you do, you could have a separate text box for this?

Comment: Hi Matthew,the issue i am having now is that the user can type text on textbox of file input and suppose to be the user cannot do that.Is this a normal behavior of IE7 input type=file? or is this a bug? - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Earlier browsers often allowed the user to type a filename in the box in input type=file control, but nowadays it has become rare. This may relate to assumed security issues. But such input is not particularly useful, especially nowadays when people use descriptive long filenames.

So it’s normal. You should expect browsers to implement input type=file via a file selection window. But allowing text input there is not a bug, just an old feature; there is no specification on the details of implementation (and they need to vary, due to system differences).